# How can I disable an Nginx cache for a specific route?

Tags: linux, nginx

I want to disable caching for a specific directory: `/sync/download`.

My environment details:

- OS Linux (rocky)
- Server: nginx/1.20.1

I added this codeblock to my nginx site configuration:

```
location ~ .*sync/download/.*$ {
                        expires -1;
                        proxy_no_cache true;
                        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                        proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
```

My full nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen   443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name ws;

        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;


        ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/cert/cert1.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/cert/cert1.key";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/ws.access.log main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/ws.error.log;




        location / {
               proxy_pass http://backend;
               proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
               proxy_set_header Request-Id $request_id;
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_cache            BPH;

                location ~ .*sync/download/.*$ {
                        expires -1;
                        proxy_no_cache true;
                        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                        proxy_pass http://backend;
        }


        }


        if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

}
```

When I delete a file, it still keeps giving a 200 result (an image already deleted)

How can I disable the cache for a specific path?

Comment: You are using terms like "route" and "media", but their relationship to Nginx configuration is unclear. Please use a more exact terminology.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache between tests?

Comment: The configuration is good the problem was that when i delete the file I was using the user interface of the site , this does not delete physically the file from my backend storage  , so when i curl the web service searching for my file (photo) i does return the photo (200 and not 404) , when i delete physically the file it returns 404 so I can say that this configuration is googd , I tested also the cache by pass , for poeple who arrives here and have the same problem , the cache by pass is the solution that i kept